# How to store data in cloud from android app?

Tags: android, cloud

Friends I'm Planning to design an application such a way that user has to login and he has to enter the data to be stored in cloud and if he opens the account the data should be edited other wise it should display the data.

Comment: Check : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 1):

I would look into solutions such as couchbase:

> Apache CouchDB on Android provides a simple way to sync your application data across devices and provide cloud backup of user data. Unlike other cloud solutions, the data is hosted on the device by Couchbase Mobile, so even when the network is down or slow (airplane, subway, backyard) the application is responsive to users.
>
> What this means for you:
>
> You can embed the rock solid distributed database, Mobile Couchbase,
> on your Android device. Your Android apps can use Apache CouchDB's
> well-proven synchronization technology. If you <3 CouchApps, you can
> deploy them as Android apps.

check it out [here](https://github.com/couchbase/Android-Couchbase)